# Applying survey weights using survey package in R

Tags: r, frequency, survey, weighted

I need some guidance in using survey weights in RStudio using the survey package.

table_1015 consists of survey data from the years 2010 to 2015 where each row is one response from a participant including information such as age, race, sex, and education level/grade (all are categorical variables). It also includes responses to questions in the survey labeled as q1, q2, q3, etc. where 1 = Yes and 0 = No and 'Missing' = NA/No Response.

I used the below code to calculate the unweighted frequencies and proportion by year and age.

```
age_1015 <- table_1015 %>%
  group_by(year, age) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(proportion = count / sum(count))
```

Example of part of the output for age_1015:

| year | age | count | proportion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 12yo | 5 | 0.185 |
| 2010 | 13yo | 8 | 0.296 |
| 2010 | 14yo | 14 | 0.519 |
| 2011 | 12yo | 3 | 0.115 |
| 2011 | 13yo | 7 | 0.269 |
| 2011 | 14yo | 16 | 0.615 |
| 2012 | 12yo | 2 | 0.118 |
| 2012 | 13yo | 4 | 0.235 |
| 2012 | 14yo | 11 | 0.647 |

How would I go about applying the following survey design object to the above? I want to calculate the weighted frequency (weighted_count) and the weighted proportion (weighted_prop).

```
srvy_des_1015 <- <- svydesign(ids = ~PSU, data = table_1015, weights = ~weight, strata = ~stratum, nest = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `svytotal` and `svyby` functions from the survey package to obtain weighted counts and proportions. it will apply the survey weights that you are included in survey design object to calculations.

```
# survey design object
srvy_des_1015 <- svydesign(ids = ~PSU, data = table_1015, weights = ~weight, strata = ~stratum, nest = TRUE)
total_weighted <- svytotal(~1, design = srvy_des_1015)
age_1015_weighted <- svyby(~1, ~year+age, design = srvy_des_1015, FUN = svytotal)
age_1015_weighted <- as.data.frame(age_1015_weighted)
# Calculate proportion
age_1015_weighted$proportion <- age_1015_weighted$V1 / as.numeric(total_weighted)
names(age_1015_weighted) <- c("year", "age", "weighted_count", "weighted_proportion")
print(age_1015_weighted)
```

`svyby` function is a wrapper for the `tapply` function in base R.formula `~1` in the `svytotal` and `svyby` functions is used to indicate that we want to sum all the observations.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful! Thank you so much. I had a follow-up question since I'm still trying to wrap my head around the syntax. How would I amend this code to calculate the weighted count and proportion by age where q1 = 1 ?

Comment: Just a note: since `svyby` doesn't even call `tapply`, I don't think it's accurate to describe it as a wrapper for `tapply`.